# In a ASP.NET program is there a location where I can I write temporary files?

Tags: asp.net

In a ASP.NET program is there a location where I can I write temporary files? Assuming a default IIS installation, the program running under anonymous user?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can pretty much save temporary files anywhere on disk as long as you have permissions.
You will just need to make sure the files are uniquely named per anonymous user.

Ideally having a dedicated "temporary" folder is a good idea, where these files will be deleted or cleaned up periodically.

Answer (score 0):

You could (and probably should) use  [`System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx). If you want .NET to take care of generating a uniquely named random, temporary file then use the [`GetTempFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) method also in `System.IO.Path`

Comment: You might not have rights to read-write into the local system(server's) Temp path.

Comment: You might not have, but obviously you would check this first - and this would hold true for any write operation. Assuming you do have permission (and all servers I've used have had this permission) then it is the preferred method set down in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

No there's no such built-in mechanism available for asp.net

What you can do is create the one witihn your application root and use it for temp operations like this.

```
string tempPath = Server.MapPath("~\\temp");
```